# Automatically call stored procedure every time other procedure is called

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a bunch of stored procedures. We would like every stored procedure to call a logging stored procedure.

Is it posible to "hook" in somewhere in SQL Server to trigger such thing. Or must we explicitly call the logging stored procedure from every other procedure?

Comment: What's the use case? If it's auditing (as in, this is not optional and no stored procedure should be able to circumvent it) you should set up something like a permanent extended events/profiler trace. If it's not as strict as that, then calling the sproc explicitly would be fine. There's no `AFTER EXECUTE` trigger in SQL Server, or something like that. (Thankfully, I should say.)

Comment: try to take a look over AO4SQL. I haven't tried it, but I think this is what you're looking for

Comment: You can't put triggers on an SP, no. You'll need to add a `EXEC` statement to your audit SP within all your other SP's.

Comment: It seems that you want wrappers or macros or procedural classes of some sort.  T-SQL does not support such functionality.